# jOOq Replacement For DSL.fieldByName

Tags: java, sql, jooq, oracle12c

I happen to have a very interesting query and problem.  We are running Oracle 12c (having moved from 11g a year or so ago) and just recently moved from jOOq 3.4.x to 3.7.3 and I would like to not use the now deprecated `DSL.fieldByName`, but I'm having trouble finding a truly like replacement from the `DSL.field` options.  Here's the query (schema name and table names obscured for security) generated in 3.4.x:

```
select 
  "v0" "pTitle", 
  "v1" "pCode", 
  "v2" "description", 
  "v3" "coid", 
  "v4" "viewCount", 
  "v5" "fileId", 
  "v6" "displayPos"
from (
  select 
    "x"."v0", 
    "x"."v1", 
    "x"."v2", 
    "x"."v3", 
    "x"."v4", 
    "x"."v5", 
    "x"."v6", 
    rownum "rn"
  from (
    select 
      "pTitle" "v0", 
      "pCode" "v1", 
      "description" "v2", 
      "coid" "v3", 
      "viewCount" "v4", 
      "fileId" "v5", 
      rownum "v6"
    from (
      select 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."TITLE" "pTitle", 
        "LibraryType"."CODE" "pCode", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."DESCRIPTION" "description", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" "coid", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" "viewCount", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" "fileId", 
        row_number() over (partition by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" order by "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" desc nulls last) "maxFileId"
      from "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"
        join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
            join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'OBJECT_TYPE'
            )
        )
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'PORTFOLIOS'
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."AC_OBJECT_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."AC_OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."SECTION" = 1
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."RELEASE_TYPE" in (
            6, 7
          )
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_OBJECT_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."AC_OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION" = 0
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"
        on (
          bitand(
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"."SENSITIVITIES") = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"."USER_ID" = 456920
        )
        join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'STATUS'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_STATUS_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'ACTIVE'
            )
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE" "LibraryType"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "LibraryType"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'PORTFOLIO_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."PORTFOLIO_TYPE_ID" = "LibraryType"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "LibraryType"."CODE" in (
                'ELEMENT', 'PROJECT', 'PROGRAM'
              )
            )
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'ACTIVITY_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" in (
                'MISSION_WITH_TECHNOLOGY', 'TECHNOLOGY_ONLY'
              )
            )
        )
        on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID"
        left outer join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"
            join "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"
            on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."PARENT_OBJECT_ID"
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'OBJECT_IMAGE'
            )
        )
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."IS_PRIMARY" = 1
        )
      where "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" is not null
      order by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" desc
    ) "alias_101861728"
    where "maxFileId" = 1
  ) "x"
  where rownum <= (0 + 10)
) 
where "rn" > 0
order by "rn"
```

And below is what I can get out of 3.7.x using the `DSL.field(Name,Class<T>)`:

```
select 
  "v0" "pTitle", 
  "v1" "pCode", 
  "v2" "description", 
  "v3" "coid", 
  "v4" "viewCount", 
  "v5" "fileId", 
  "v6" "displayPos"
from (
  select 
    "x"."v0", 
    "x"."v1", 
    "x"."v2", 
    "x"."v3", 
    "x"."v4", 
    "x"."v5", 
    "x"."v6", 
    rownum "rn"
  from (
    select 
      pTitle "v0", 
      pCode "v1", 
      description "v2", 
      coid "v3", 
      viewCount "v4", 
      fileId "v5", 
      rownum "v6"
    from (
      select 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."TITLE" "pTitle", 
        "LibraryType"."CODE" "pCode", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."DESCRIPTION" "description", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" "coid", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" "viewCount", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" "fileId", 
        row_number() over (partition by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" order by "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" desc nulls last) "maxFileId"
      from "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"
        join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
            join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'OBJECT_TYPE'
            )
        )
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'PORTFOLIOS'
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."AC_OBJECT_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."AC_OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."SECTION" = 1
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."RELEASE_TYPE" in (
            6, 7
          )
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_OBJECT_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."AC_OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION" = 0
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"
        on (
          bitand(
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"."SENSITIVITIES") = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"."USER_ID" = 456920
        )
        join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'STATUS'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_STATUS_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'ACTIVE'
            )
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE" "LibraryType"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "LibraryType"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'PORTFOLIO_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."PORTFOLIO_TYPE_ID" = "LibraryType"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "LibraryType"."CODE" in (
                'ELEMENT', 'PROJECT', 'PROGRAM'
              )
            )
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'ACTIVITY_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" in (
                'MISSION_WITH_TECHNOLOGY', 'TECHNOLOGY_ONLY'
              )
            )
        )
        on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID"
        left outer join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"
            join "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"
            on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."PARENT_OBJECT_ID"
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'OBJECT_IMAGE'
            )
        )
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."IS_PRIMARY" = 1
        )
      where "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" is not null
      order by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" desc
    ) "alias_101861728"
    where "maxFileId" = 1
  ) "x"
  where rownum <= (0 + 10)
) 
where "rn" > 0
order by "rn"
```

The important thing in the above is that we lose the quotes around our aliases.  Now the Java code itself had to be interesting.  It seems that jOOq (in both 3.4.x and 3.7.x) "forgets" to use the aliases when it's doing its (wonderful) limit and offset simulations for Oracle, so I've had to do some trickery (3.4.x):

```
final LkuCode libraryType = LkuCode.LKU_CODE.as("LibraryType");
final Field<Integer> maxFileId = DSL.rowNumber()
        .over(DSL.partitionBy(co.OBJECT_ID).orderBy(f.FILE_ID.desc().nullsLast()))
        .as("maxFileId");
final Field<String> pTitle = p.TITLE.as("pTitle");
final Field<String> pCode = libraryType.CODE.as("pCode");
final Field<String> description = p.DESCRIPTION.as("description");
final Field<BigDecimal> coid = co.OBJECT_ID.as("coid");
final Field<BigDecimal> viewCount = co.VIEW_COUNT.as("viewCount");
final Field<BigDecimal> fileId = f.FILE_ID.as("fileId");
final Field<String> pTitleAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(pTitle.getDataType(), pTitle.getName());
final Field<String> pCodeAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(pCode.getDataType(), pCode.getName());
final Field<String> descriptionAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(description.getDataType(), description.getName());
final Field<BigDecimal> coidAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(coid.getDataType(), coid.getName());
final Field<BigDecimal> viewCountAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(viewCount.getDataType(), viewCount.getName());
final Field<BigDecimal> fileIdAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(fileId.getDataType(), fileId.getName());
final Field<Integer> displayPos = (DSL.rownum().as("displayPos"));

final BigDecimal[] rts = new BigDecimal[] {RELEASE_TYPE_PUBLIC,
            RELEASE_TYPE_INTERNAL};
final Condition limitByRelease = (cort.SECTION.equal(BigDecimal
        .valueOf(AccessControlConstants.CORE_OBJECT_CHAR_ARRAY_PUBLIC_DATA)).and(cort.RELEASE_TYPE
        .in(rts)));

final BigDecimal uid = new BigDecimal(DatabaseManager.getUid());

final Result<Record7<String, String, String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, Integer>> result;
try (Connection readConn = DatabaseManager.getConnection(false);
        final DSLContext readContext = DatabaseManager.getBuilder(readConn)) {
    final Select<Record7<String, String, String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, Integer>> query = readContext
            .select(pTitleAliasField, pCodeAliasField, descriptionAliasField, coidAliasField,
                    viewCountAliasField, fileIdAliasField, displayPos)
            .from(readContext
                    .select(pTitle, pCode, description, coid, viewCount, fileId, maxFileId)
                    .from(co
                            .join(lc.join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.OBJECT_TYPE)))
                            .onKey(Keys.CO_LC_OTI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.OBJECTTYPE_PORTFOLIOS))
                            .join(cort)
                            .onKey(Keys.CORT_CO___FK)
                            .and(limitByRelease)
                            .join(cos)
                            .onKey(Keys.COS_CO___FK)
                            .and(cos.SECTION.equal(BigDecimal
                                    .valueOf(AccessControlConstants.CORE_OBJECT_CHAR_ARRAY_SELF)))
                            .join(tu)
                            .on(DSL.bitAnd(cos.SENSITIVITIES, tu.SENSITIVITIES)
                                    .equal(cos.SENSITIVITIES).and(tu.USER_ID.equal(uid))))
                    .join(p
                            .join(lc.join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.PORTFOLIO_STATUS)))
                            .onKey(Keys.P_LC_PSI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_STATUS_ACTIVE))
                            .join(libraryType.join(lct)
                                    .on(libraryType.LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID.equal(lct.LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID))
                                    .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE)))
                            .on(p.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_ID.equal(libraryType.LKU_CODE_ID))
                            .and(libraryType.CODE
                                    .in(new String[] {LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_ELEMENT,
                                            LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_PROJECT,
                                            LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_PROGRAM}))
                            .join(lc.join(lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.ACTIVITY_TYPE)))
                            .onKey(Keys.P_LC_ATI___FK)
                            .and(lc.CODE.in(LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_ACTIVITY_TYPE_TECHNOLOGY)))
                    .on(p.PORTFOLIO_ID.equal(co.OBJECT_ID))
                    .leftOuterJoin(
                            li
                                    .join(f)
                                    .on(li.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID.equal(f.PARENT_OBJECT_ID))
                                    .join(lc
                                            .join(lct)
                                            .onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                            .and(lct.CODE_TYPE
                                                    .equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE)))
                                    .onKey(Keys.LI_LC_LITI___FK)
                                    .and(lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_OBJECT_IMAGE)))
                    .on(li.PORTFOLIO_ID.equal(co.OBJECT_ID).and(
                            li.IS_PRIMARY.equal(byteOne)))
                    .where(co.VIEW_COUNT.isNotNull()).orderBy(co.VIEW_COUNT.desc()))
            .where(maxFileId.equal(Integer.valueOf(1))).limit(numberOfObjects).offset(startNumber - 1);

    result = query.fetch();
```

Now, I do understand that I can use SQL `EXISTS` instead of joining the SENSITVITIES and RELEASE_TYPES tables (as well as a couple of other tables), but this is what I'm doing right now and that's not really pertinent to this question.  If there's something else that I can do, I'd love to hear it.  I've tried not using any aliases at all, but things then get mucked up:

```
    final Select<Record7<String, String, String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, Integer>> query = readContext
            .select(HomeDAO.p.PORTFOLIO_TITLE, portfolioType.CODE, HomeDAO.p.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION,
                    HomeDAO.co.OBJECT_ID, HomeDAO.co.VIEW_COUNT, HomeDAO.f.FILE_ID, displayPos)
            .from(readContext
                    .select(HomeDAO.p.PORTFOLIO_TITLE, portfolioType.CODE, HomeDAO.p.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION,
                            HomeDAO.co.OBJECT_ID, HomeDAO.co.VIEW_COUNT, HomeDAO.f.FILE_ID, maxFileId)
                    .from(HomeDAO.co
                            .join(HomeDAO.lc.join(HomeDAO.lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(HomeDAO.lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.OBJECT_TYPE)))
                            .onKey(Keys.CO_LC_OTI___FK)
                            .and(HomeDAO.lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.OBJECTTYPE_PORTFOLIOS))
                            .join(HomeDAO.cort)
                            .onKey(Keys.CORT_CO___FK)
                            .and(limitByRelease)
                            .join(HomeDAO.cos)
                            .onKey(Keys.COS_CO___FK)
                            .and(HomeDAO.cos.SECTION.equal(BigDecimal
                                    .valueOf(AccessControlConstants.CORE_OBJECT_CHAR_ARRAY_SELF)))
                            .join(HomeDAO.tu)
                            .on(DSL.bitAnd(HomeDAO.cos.SENSITIVITIES, HomeDAO.tu.SENSITIVITIES)
                                    .equal(HomeDAO.cos.SENSITIVITIES).and(HomeDAO.tu.USER_ID.equal(uid))))
                    .join(HomeDAO.p
                            .join(HomeDAO.lc.join(HomeDAO.lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(HomeDAO.lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.PORTFOLIO_STATUS)))
                            .onKey(Keys.P_LC_PSI___FK)
                            .and(HomeDAO.lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_STATUS_ACTIVE))
                            .join(portfolioType.join(HomeDAO.lct)
                                    .on(portfolioType.LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID.equal(HomeDAO.lct.LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID))
                                    .and(HomeDAO.lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE)))
                            .on(HomeDAO.p.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_ID.equal(portfolioType.LKU_CODE_ID))
                            .and(portfolioType.CODE
                                    .in(new String[] {LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_ELEMENT,
                                            LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_PROJECT,
                                            LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_TYPE_PROGRAM}))
                            .join(HomeDAO.lc.join(HomeDAO.lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                    .and(HomeDAO.lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.ACTIVITY_TYPE)))
                            .onKey(Keys.P_LC_ATI___FK)
                            .and(HomeDAO.lc.CODE.in(LkuCodeLookup.PORTFOLIO_ACTIVITY_TYPE_TECHNOLOGY)))
                    .on(HomeDAO.p.PORTFOLIO_ID.equal(HomeDAO.co.OBJECT_ID))
                    .leftOuterJoin(
                            HomeDAO.li
                                    .join(HomeDAO.f)
                                    .on(HomeDAO.li.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID.equal(HomeDAO.f.PARENT_OBJECT_ID))
                                    .join(HomeDAO.lc
                                            .join(HomeDAO.lct)
                                            .onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                                            .and(HomeDAO.lct.CODE_TYPE
                                                    .equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE)))
                                    .onKey(Keys.LI_LC_LITI___FK)
                                    .and(HomeDAO.lc.CODE.equal(LkuCodeLookup.LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_OBJECT_IMAGE)))
                    .on(HomeDAO.li.PORTFOLIO_ID.equal(HomeDAO.co.OBJECT_ID).and(
                            HomeDAO.li.IS_PRIMARY.equal(HomeDAO.byteOne)))
                    .where(HomeDAO.co.VIEW_COUNT.isNotNull()).orderBy(HomeDAO.co.VIEW_COUNT.desc()))
            .where(maxFileId.equal(Integer.valueOf(1))).limit(numberOfObjects).offset(startNumber - 1);
```

Which yields:

```
select 
  "v0" "TITLE", 
  "v1" "CODE", 
  "v2" "DESCRIPTION", 
  "v3" "OBJECT_ID", 
  "v4" "VIEW_COUNT", 
  "v5" "FILE_ID", 
  "v6" "displayPos"
from (
  select 
    "x"."v0", 
    "x"."v1", 
    "x"."v2", 
    "x"."v3", 
    "x"."v4", 
    "x"."v5", 
    "x"."v6", 
    rownum "rn"
  from (
    select 
      "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."TITLE" "v0", 
      "PortfolioType"."CODE" "v1", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."DESCRIPTION" "v2", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" "v3", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" "v4", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" "v5", 
      row_number "v6"
    from (
      select 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."TITLE", 
        "PortfolioType"."CODE", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."DESCRIPTION", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID", 
        row_number() over (partition by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" order by "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" desc nulls last) "maxFileId"
      from "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"
        join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
            join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'OBJECT_TYPE'
            )
        )
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'PORTFOLIOS'
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."AC_OBJECT_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."AC_OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."SECTION" = 1
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_RELEASE_TYPE"."RELEASE_TYPE" in (
            6, 7
          )
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."AC_OBJECT_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."AC_OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SECTION" = 0
        )
        join "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"
        on (
          bitand(
            "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES", 
            "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"."SENSITIVITIES") = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_SENSITIVITIES"."SENSITIVITIES"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."USERS"."USER_ID" = 456920
        )
        join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'STATUS'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."PORTFOLIO_STATUS_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'ACTIVE'
            )
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE" "PortfolioType"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "PortfolioType"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'PORTFOLIO_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "PortfolioType"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "PortfolioType"."CODE" in (
                'ELEMENT', 'PROJECT', 'PROGRAM'
              )
            )
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'ACTIVITY_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" in (
                'MISSION_WITH_TECHNOLOGY', 'TECHNOLOGY_ONLY'
              )
            )
        )
        on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID"
        left outer join (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"
            join "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"
            on "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."PARENT_OBJECT_ID"
            join (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"
                join "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"
                on (
                  "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID"
                  and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE_TYPE"."CODE_TYPE" = 'LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE'
                )
            )
            on (
              "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_TYPE_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."LKU_CODE_ID"
              and "SCHEMA_A"."LKU_CODE"."CODE" = 'OBJECT_IMAGE'
            )
        )
        on (
          "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."LIBRARY_ITEM_ID" = "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID"
          and "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY_ITEMS"."IS_PRIMARY" = 1
        )
      where "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" is not null
      order by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" desc
    ) "alias_62833117"
    where "maxFileId" = 1
  ) "x"
  where rownum <= (0 + 10)
) 
where "rn" > 0
order by "rn"
```

This cases a SQL exception (`ORA-00904: "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID": invalid identifier` -- Error at Line: 26 Column: 7).

Using just the first set of aliases causes bad SQL queries because jOOq's simulated `LIMIT` doesn't use the aliases, but the full name.

```
final LkuCode libraryType = LkuCode.LKU_CODE.as("LibraryType");
final Field<Integer> maxFileId = DSL.rowNumber()
        .over(DSL.partitionBy(co.OBJECT_ID).orderBy(f.FILE_ID.desc().nullsLast()))
        .as("maxFileId");
final Field<String> pTitle = p.TITLE.as("pTitle");
final Field<String> pCode = libraryType.CODE.as("pCode");
final Field<String> description = p.DESCRIPTION.as("description");
final Field<BigDecimal> coid = co.OBJECT_ID.as("coid");
final Field<BigDecimal> viewCount = co.VIEW_COUNT.as("viewCount");
final Field<BigDecimal> fileId = f.FILE_ID.as("fileId");

    final Select<Record7<String, String, String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, Integer>> query = readContext
            .select(pTitle, pCode, description, coid, viewCount, fileId, displayPos)
            .from(readContext
                     .select(pTitle, pCode, description, coid, viewCount, fileId, maxFileId)
```

Yields the snippet:

```
select 
  "v0" "pTitle", 
  "v1" "pCode", 
  "v2" "description", 
  "v3" "coid", 
  "v4" "viewCount", 
  "v5" "fileId", 
  "v6" "displayPos"
from (
  select 
    "x"."v0", 
    "x"."v1", 
    "x"."v2", 
    "x"."v3", 
    "x"."v4", 
    "x"."v5", 
    "x"."v6", 
    rownum "rn"
  from (
    select 
      "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."TITLE" "v0", 
      "LibraryType"."CODE" "v1", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."DESCRIPTION" "v2", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" "v3", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" "v4", 
      "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" "v5", 
      rownum "v6"
    from (
      select 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."TITLE" "pTitle", 
        "LibraryType"."CODE" "pCode", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."LIBRARY"."DESCRIPTION" "description", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" "coid", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."VIEW_COUNT" "viewCount", 
        "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" "fileId", 
        row_number() over (partition by "SCHEMA_A"."AC_ASSOC_TABLE"."OBJECT_ID" order by "SCHEMA_A"."FILES"."FILE_ID" desc nulls last) "maxFileId"
```

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't happen, and I can't seem to reproduce it right away. Are you sure you're using `field(Name,Class<T>)` and not, perhaps, `field(String,Class<T>)`? Also, I might misread your question, but I think you've only posted the working code using jOOQ 3.4, not the failing Java code using 3.7, is that right?

Comment: I would have loved to have had more, but hit character limits and had to make "the cut".  You know what... I had forgotten that `.getName()` returns a `String`.  Do I have to make a Field, a Name, and then that second "alias" field?  If you were writing like code, how would you do that aliasing?  Just an example showing one set of aliases (sans the query) would be highly appreciated (perhaps an example for pTitle and an alias field if you have to have one).

Comment: Quick follow-on question: is there a way to remove the need for the second set of variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a very big question, and I'm a bit lost. What do you mean by "how would you do that aliasing"? And what do you mean by the "second set of variables"?

Comment: Big question?  What would make you say that?! (just kidding)

Simplified, what I'm doing is as follows:
1) get a bunch of Library entries and their Files
2) now boil it down to one Library->*File entry per Library item (that file item is going to be the "primary" file item)
3) Get only rows n-m (again, Oracle, so jOOq simulates)

Because of this, I'm aliasing columns in my selects (otherwise things break), but I have to make two variables -- the first that tells the inner most select to give a column an alias and the second that the other selects use.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Ran out of characters.  Is there something better than:

`final Field<String> pTitle = p.TITLE.as("pTitle");`
`final Field<String> pTitleAliasField = DSL.fieldByName(pTitle.getDataType(), pTitle.getName());`

The first being for the inner-most select and the second being for the other selects.

Also, how can I get a Name object from that first variable?

Comment: @LukasEder is this the recommended way?  The first field, aliasing the column: `final Field<String> pTitle = HomeDAO.p.PORTFOLIO_TITLE.as("pTitle");` and the second, that I use to reference the alias in the outer selects: `final Field<String> pTitleAliasField = DSL.field(DSL.name(pTitle.getName()), pTitle.getDataType());`?  If so, since it's the methods you mentioned, can you please make an answer so that I may give you credit?  And thank you for helping me work through this -- I had forgotten that `.getName` returned a String and not a Name.

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way from what I can tell. If you're still unsure, perhaps you can ask a new question, though :) Perhaps if you remove most of the query and focus only on the aliasing and dereferencing of fields, it will be more clear. I'll answer this one, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell in the comments, you might be confusing `field(Name,Class<T>)` with `field(String,Class<T>)`

- The first (`field(Name,Class<T>)`) produces a field with a formal, possibly qualified column name, which is quoted by default, by jOOQ. This is the one you should use here. More info here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names
- The latter (`field(String,Class<T>)`) produces a field with some plain SQL content. So, jOOQ cannot quote that string because the semantics of the string is any arbitrary SQL expression, not necessarily an identifier. More info here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql